# Как из одного словаря сформировать другой C#

Tags: c#, linq

У меня есть словарь предметов `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, NZMark>> subjectsDatesMarks`, который хранит список дат с оценками.

Каким образом я могу привести его к следующему виду: `Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<string, NZMark>> datesSubjectsMarks`?

```
public enum NZMark
{
    One = 1,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Eleven,
    Twelve,
    WasAbsent,
    NotCertified,
    Exempted,
    Studied
}
```

Минимальный воспроизводимый пример:

```
var subjectsDatesMarks = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, NZMark>>();

subjectsDatesMarks.Add("math", new Dictionary<DateTime, NZMark>());
subjectsDatesMarks["math"].Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 20), (NZMark)8);
subjectsDatesMarks["math"].Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 21), (NZMark)8);
subjectsDatesMarks["math"].Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 22), (NZMark)10);

subjectsDatesMarks.Add("PE", new Dictionary<DateTime, NZMark>());
subjectsDatesMarks["PE"].Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 20), (NZMark)10);
subjectsDatesMarks["PE"].Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 21), (NZMark)11);
subjectsDatesMarks["PE"].Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 22), (NZMark)10);

var datesSubjectsMarks = MagickTransform(subjectsDatesMarks); // та самая функция для преобразования, которая мне нужна
var mathMark2021_03_22 = datesSubjectsMarks[new DateTime(2021, 03, 22)]["math"]; // 10
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну например так:

```cs
Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<string, NZMark>> datesSubjectsMarks =
    subjectsDatesMarks.SelectMany(e => e.Value.Select(dtmark => (subj: e.Key,
                                                                 dt: dtmark.Key,
                                                                 mark: dtmark.Value)))
                      .GroupBy(triple => triple.dt)
                      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                                    g => g.ToDictionary(triple => triple.subj,
                                                        triple => triple.mark));
```

[Проверка](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

---

Ещё один вариант с query syntax:

```cs
Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<string, NZMark>> datesSubjectsMarks =
   (from kvp in subjectsDatesMarks
    let subj = kvp.Key
    from dtmark in kvp.Value
    let dt = dtmark.Key
    let mark = dtmark.Value
    group (subj, mark) by dt)
   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                 g => g.ToDictionary(v => v.subj, v => v.mark));
```

Comment: Надеюсь, что кто-то придумает более изящное решение.

Comment: Вполне себе изящное решение.

Comment: @aepot: Спасибо! Но вдруг кто-то придумает получше?

Comment: Получше только выкинуть к чертям словари и хранить данные в списке из классов. И тем же линком их оттуда дергать в нужном виде.

Comment: @aepot: Ну кстати тоже интересный подход. Плоское хранение как в базе, и словари как индексы над этой базой.

Comment: По сути, это должна быть некая форма `transpose` (которого, правда, нет в LINQ, т. к. `Enumerable.Zip` не имеет перегрузки с последовательностью последовательностей). Хаскелисты, ау!